# Undefined index error when showing logged in user info

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following in my AppController:

```
function beforeRender()
{
    $this->set('user', $this->Auth->user());
}
```

and then I show the user info like so:

`<?php echo $user['User']['username']; ?>`

but it gives an error:

`Undefined index: User [APP/View/Layouts/default.ctp, line 46]`

I'm using CakePHP 2.0. What's causing the error?

Thanks

**EDIT: Doing `$user['username']` fixes the issue but this isn't ideal as I NEED to declare the model as I want to access other information that is linked e.g. `$user['Profile']['firstname']`**

If I `debug($user)` I get the info but not in the correct way as I'm not able to specify the model and get the relationships (which do work as I use them elsewhere).

My relationship SHOULD BE:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [username] => cameron
            [password] => 3b8cdb0c849f00f3634d9b29def1dac4e9235795
            [email] => cameron@driz.co.uk
            [status] => 0
            [code] => ea817b572e5199698274c7c0d61ee150
        )

    [Profile] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [firstname] => Cameron
            [lastname] => Drysdale
            [gender] => Male
            [dob] => 1987-06-26
            [bio] => <p>I'm the developer of this application.</p>
            [user_id] => 6
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [username] => cameron
                    [password] => 3b8cdb0c849f00f3634d9b29def1dac4e9235795
                    [email] => cameron@driz.co.uk
                    [status] => 0
                    [code] => ea817b572e5199698274c7c0d61ee150
                )

        )

)
```

but when I try and get the logged in user info I only get the first array

Answer (score 4):

You won't get the Profile information doing $this->Auth->user(), only the User model data. For what you intend to do, you might need something like this in your app_controller:

```
<?php
$this->loadModel('User');
$this->User->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
    'contain' => array('Profile', 'OtherRelatedModels')
));
?>
```

assuming that your are using the containable behavior.

Comment: This answer is correct. I'm assuming that just as with your previous questions, you may not properly follow through and accept it, so I've upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by `$user['User']` not existing. That key/index does not appear in the `$user` array.

Do a `var_dump()` on `$user` to see what it contains before trying to access `$user['User']['username']`.

Comment: If I `debug($user)` I get the info but not in the correct way as I'm not able to specify the model and get the relationships (which do work as I use them elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you are trying to achieve, but this:

```
$u=array();
$u['User'] = $this->Auth->user();
$this->set('user', $u);
```

produces:

```
Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [username] => admin
                    [role] => admin
                    [etc] => etc...
```

allowing

`echo $user['User']['id']` etc. to work.

but perhaps elaborate; I expect there's an alternative way to achieve what you want, as the `Auth->user()` method just returns the current users details that you specify at logging in (more or less)

Comment: I'm trying to access my user info for a logged in user. I use two tables for a person and I can't get user profile such as firstname etc as it's not requesting the model...

Comment: And don't forget you can access Auth information with: `$this->Session->read('Auth.user.field_name')` in a view.